# Would it be possible to use "were looking" here?

Tags: progressive-aspect

We didn’t drink very much at all –one vodka each- but other young people had been drinking heavily all evening. Some of the dancers **looked** quite drunk.

Would it be possible to use the continuous "were looking" in this example because it is a temporary state.(even if in this case it is an opinion, so used as a stative verb)

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/112456062/10-Texts-to-Revise-Mixed-Tenses-With-Key

Comment: Yes, it is, because the moderate drinkers were presumably observing the dancers for some time.

Comment: Why do you think "look" is an opinion verb? And what rule of grammar says opinion verbs cannot be used in the past continuous?